# Tool for parsing XML in Hadoop

Tags: xml, scala, hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I want to know if there is any tool which i can use to parse XML files in **hadoop** environment. I know using map reduce we can parse XML files if there is no tools available than parsing is better in which language scala, java or pig ?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hadoop environment will typically have Java available.  So I'd use the "Java Architecture for XML Binding" or JAXB.

It is relatively easy to use, and has development strategies that include the major approaches:

- You have XML that someone else has defined that you want to access within Java.
- You have Java data structures that you want to represent in XML.

It has a lot of features, but don't worry about adding all the bells and whistles unless you need them.  It is also reasonably fast.

[You can find the learning path for it here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/).

Scala is also an excellent choice, but it suffers a bit from a higher learning curve (which isn't that high if you already know Java and have some exposure to Lambda based languages).  The documentation is reasonable, but sometimes it falls just short of the documentation available for Java.

Scala would be my second choice for a team that didn't have a track record of delivering in Scala.  It's not harder, and for some problems Scala is a lot easier, but without a smattering of Scala experience, one tends to solve problems in Scala leveraging non-Scala approaches.

Pig is a language that I've had limited experience with, so I'll reserve commentary.

Comment: If xml file size is huge than parsing will be easy using JAXB ?

Comment: is there any tool to parse xml ?

Comment: JAXB is the tool to parse Java.  It can handle reasonably sized XML files; but if you're really talking about massive XML files, you might want to use a smaller component of the Java XML parsing tools called SAX.  The primary optimizations SAX offers is that when your XML is so large you cannot hold it your program's memory, you can more easily skip the portions of the XML you don't care about.  This skipping can be done in both toolkits, but SAX is so primitive that it's easier to bend it to handle odd scenarios (at least for me); but if you do, treat it as part of a pushdown parser.